# How to prevent auto correction / suggestion of text in textarea?

Tags: html, xhtml, jstl

We provide a page where a student can provide his answer to a certain question. This information is obtained via an input text area box and we would prefer that the browser doesn't auto correct and indicate grammatical errors on the student responses (e.g. obey is correct but obay is wrong). The browser shows a red underline if there are grammatical mistakes. How do I prevent this across all browsers.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a programming question at this point in time.  I'm betting you are using Firefox which has this option built-in in current version (see http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Using%20the%20spell%20checker#Disabling_automatic_spell_checking) for FF specific.
Alternatively, you can standardize your school to use browser that does not have this capability out of the box. for example: IE8.  I don't use Opera / Safari, so I am not sure about those 2.

Comment: @Jimmy: I think it'd be very sad if another educational institution limited their students to IE.

Comment: @Matti hehe, just trying to be pragmatic here.  If it works, well... there is always Lynx, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 defined a new [attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#spelling-and-grammar-checking) for this... `spellcheck=false`

I don't think it can be done in previous versions of (X)HTML.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible other than disabling/uninstalling that feature in the browsers themselves. Make sure you uninstall their word processors too, while you are at it!